# Decorate function Typescript definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, variadic-tuple-types

Trying to create TypeScript definition for the following "decorator" function (which i have as 3rd party dependency in my TS project):

```js
const decorate = (...args) => {
  const [methods, ...decorators] = args.reverse();

  return methods.map((method) => decorators.reduce((acc, decorator) => decorator(acc), method));
};

// usage: 

const [decorated1, decorated2] = decorate(decorator1, decorator2, [entry1, entry2])
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to create definition for this function without endless amount of overloads for each set of parameters amount?

Thanks

Comment: Let me know if it works for you https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends a lot on how detailed you want to get.

The following is not a full answer but here are some ingredients to get you started ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/PTAEEkDsHMCcFMAmBLekAuoCMAoP6BPAB3lAHE15ZkBjAHgDEA%20UAXlAG0AiCyK2gDSgAhkSIAbVIi5CGAXXzFSAWVEAZZAGd0dACoBlUPAAe6NIk0jIBDnJascoJ6ANHT5yx2SQAZlRdCAHTB3n6woABKCs4xoAD8nLz89LpMQcGqRBradBFM0bFOAFyOzq4mZpAWnAWFCbalhSUxfABuVHg4hCQu8NqZ2ZjsA1o6HFhCAExCAMx2nSAQMAgoaJiTnd2k%20gD2AK6wNPCMAHJuldUAFJpFVgQAlGwswtb2jaAMZxUeoNe3of59I9WM9rO8Ygl9ODnLc2h0ukoXMJYNB4DpPucfn87sDQQQ3jEMd8qpZsS8Hk9QADwrpoU4ErTCsVQHDYIoerpYC9ND4drAALa7A5HOj6eycLiaHb80iovjUGigdBcyA8vn87zQJUAC1IUuF8BkoH0Ci2LhVaoFumRqJ0qTYEqlMtAcuSSotvIFmp1pHQNrRRt0ChwNB2qswiHgoa56D571up0xJN%20NxxlPJTEuPkgt0%20uJTt053M9gv2h2OQvLpyYTHzRdVJetKLRen96JONfe7D2VXgPm8SAAhJ1Q%20HQJHo8IzIh4wXzcX1ZWRZKy0cuLXKfXLfym7a6Fw-c30Ouu%20Oo3yp3zLpdhLcVwauPmD22uCJLM%20j4%20cEA)).

---

*Ingredient: Transforming arrays of types*

```
// Ingredient 1

type Generic<F> = ["Generic, applied", F]

type MapList<TS extends any[]> =
    TS extends [infer T, ...infer R]
        ? [Generic<T>, ...MapList<R>]
        :
    TS extends []
        ? []
        :
    never


// Resolves to [Generic<1>, Generic<2>, Generic<3>]
type TestMapList = MapList<[1, 2, 3]>
```

---

*Ingredient 2: Applying a decorator that generically transforms a functions signature*

I think your decorators need to be correctly typed in order for this to work. Something like this could work.

```
// Ingredient 2


type Source<FN extends (s: any) => any> =
    FN extends (s: infer S) => any
        ? S
        : never

type Target<FN extends (s: any) => any> =
    FN extends (s: any) => infer T
        ? T
        : never

type TransformSource<S> = ["some generic transforming the source", S]
type TransformTarget<T> = ["some generic transforming the target", T]

const decorator
    : <FN extends (s: any) => any>(fn: FN) => (s: TransformSource<Source<FN>>) => TransformTarget<Target<FN>>
    = undefined!


const decorated
    : (s: TransformSource<"source">) => TransformTarget<"target">
    = decorator((a: "source") => "target" as "target")
```

---

*Correctly typing a compose function*

Since at least TS 4.1(?) it is possible to provide correct typings for `compose` and `pipe` functions.

https://dev.to/babak/introducing-the-recursive-pipe-and-compose-types-3g9o

---

I think you'll need to put in some work but a combination of these building blocks should get you there.